# Interface generics and instanceof

Tags: java, generics, interface, instanceof

My interface has a generic type argument. Any class which would implement the interface has to declare this type, so later users of it will know what they get back. Now, I need to do checks with instanceof on these classes to see if they are an instance of Action.

My question is: what will instanceof return if i did:

```
if (SomeAction instanceof Action<?>) {
    . . .

}
```

with this `SomeAction` class:

```
public class SomeAction implements Action<String> {
    . . .

}
```

Will it return true, or false? And what if I did `SomeAction instanceof Action<Integer>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't care about the generic type when you use `instanceof`. To quote the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCast):

> *Because the Java compiler erases all type parameters in generic code, you cannot verify which parameterized type for a generic type is being used at runtime*

So, you can test against `Action<?>` or `Action`, but you will get a compiler error if you try to test against `Action<Integer>`. The error message is very informative:

> *Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type Action<Integer>. Use the form Action<?> instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime*

Comment: Ok, that is very clear. Is it actually better to leave behind the <?>, or does that make no difference?

Comment: @Creator13: As far as I understand it makes no difference at all, but since the error message prefers the `<?>` syntax, I would stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it and it returns true.

Also if you leave out generics all together, like this:

```
if (SomeAction instanceof Action) {
    . . .

}
```

If you try to actually include a generic type for Action in that *if* operation the code doesn't compile, with the message:

> illegal generic type for instance of

for instance:

```
if (action instanceof Action<String>) {
            System.out.println("is Action");
} else {
            System.out.println("is not Action");
}
```